# Incorrect regex_replace while decoding to Hebrew

Tags: google-bigquery

The code below is not working because my regex_replace is not handling white spaces as it should. Help!
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
decode(word string) AS ((
SELECT
IF
(STARTS_WITH(word, '&#x'),
safe.code_points_to_STRING(ARRAY(
SELECT
CAST(value AS int64)
FROM
UNNEST(SPLIT(REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(word, '[^a-zA-Z0-9&#]', ''), '&#', '0'),';')) value
WHERE
NOT value = '' )),
word) ));
WITH
DATA AS (
SELECT
`'&#x5E9;&#x5D1;&#x5D7;&#x5D9;&#x5DD; &#x5DC;&#x5E1;&#x5D5;&#x5E7;&#x5D5;&#x5DC;&#x5D5;&#x5D1;&#x5E1;&#x5E7;&#x5D9;, &#x5D4;&#x5D0;&#x5E8;&#x5D9;&#x5E1;: &#x5D9;&#x5D3;&#x5E2;&#x5E0;&#x5D5; &#x5E9;&#x5EA;&#x5D4;&#x5D9;&#x5D4; &#x5DE;&#x5DC;&#x5D7;&#x5DE;&#x5D4;'` txt )
SELECT
(
SELECT
STRING_AGG(decode(word), ' ')
FROM
UNNEST(SPLIT(txt, ' ')) word ) AS Hebrew_txt
FROM
DATA ;

The expected result: שבחים לסוקולובסקי, האריס: ידענו שתהיה מלחמה

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
create temp function decode(word string) as ((
  select if(starts_with(word, '&#x'), 
    safe.code_points_to_string(array(
      select ifnull(safe_cast(value as int64), ascii(value))
      from unnest(split(replace(word, '&#', '0'),';')) value
      where not value = ''
    )), 
    word)
));
select (
    select string_agg(decode(word), ' ')
    from unnest(split(txt, ' ')) word
  ) as Hebrew_txt
from data
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]